# Add a column value to an array in another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Source json data

```
{"ID": "ABC", "Amt": 23077, "col": [{"Seq": 1, "Pct": 1.5, "Sh": 1},{"Seq": 2, "Pct": 1.2, "Sh": 2.5}]}
```

With below structure

```
ID:string
Amt:long
Col:array
    element:struct
        Seq:int
        Pct:double
        Sh:double
```

I have a dataframe with below output

```
+----+-------+-----------------------------+
|ID  |Amt    |col                          |
+----+-------+-----------------------------+
|ABC |23077  |[[1, 1.5, 1], [2, 1.2, 2.5]] |
+------------+-----------------------------+
```

I need to add Amt column to the col towards the end of the each element in the array.

```
+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|ID  |Amt    |col1                                       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
|ABC |23077  |[[1, 1.5, 1, 23077], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 23077]] |
+----+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Spark version >= 2.4, you can use `transform` to add elements to the struct:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "Amt",
    "ID",
    "transform(col, x -> struct(x.Seq as Seq, x.Pct as Pct, x.Sh as Sh, Amt)) as col1"
)

df2.show(false)
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
|Amt  |ID |col1                                        |
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
|23077|ABC|[[1, 1.5, 1.0, 23077], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 23077]]|
+-----+---+--------------------------------------------+
```

For older Spark versions, you can explode the array of structs and reconstruct them:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("Amt","ID","inline(col)")
            .groupBy("ID","Amt")
            .agg(collect_list(struct(col("Seq"),col("Pct"),col("Sh"),col("Amt"))).as("col1"))

df2.show(false)
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------+
|ID |Amt  |col1                                        |
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------+
|ABC|23077|[[1, 1.5, 1.0, 23077], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 23077]]|
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks that worked. i am able to do some calculations based on this. is there any way we can calculate the following: for the second array we need to minus the last element of previous array with its last element of the array eg 23077 - 23077. the output is [[1, 1.5, 1.0, 23077], [2, 1.2, 2.5, 0]]

Comment: new problem -> ask new question -> get new answer, please. @justanothertekguy

Comment: is there any documentation for transform ? for some reason cant seem to find anything!

Comment: See the [SQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#transform)